# How to install smarty template engine in ubuntu? How to use it with php?

Tags: smarty

I am learning [smarty template engine](http://www.smarty.net/). Could any one please tell me how to install it in ubuntu as i am unable to find good tutorial

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help, [Quick Install](http://www.smarty.net/quick_install) and [Basic Installation](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/installing.smarty.basic)